# ERROR java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/geotools/factory/StrictHints;

Tags: java, android, geotools, siddhi

I am creating an Android app and using an extension getting from maven. The extension use geotools classes, but When I execute the app I have de following error:

```
2020-04-20 21:51:52.743 32378-32378/uca.es.geoprueba E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: uca.es.geoprueba, PID: 32378
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{uca.es.geoprueba/uca.es.geoprueba.MainActivity}: org.wso2.siddhi.core.exception.SiddhiAppCreationException: Error on '93c507cd-f021-434b-8cde-03c49093feb5' @ Line: 1. Position: 233, near 'geo:within(longitude,latitude,"{'type':'Polygon','coordinates':[[[0,0],[0,2],[1,2],[1,0],[0,0]]]}")'.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2946)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
     Caused by: org.wso2.siddhi.core.exception.SiddhiAppCreationException: Error on '93c507cd-f021-434b-8cde-03c49093feb5' @ Line: 1. Position: 233, near 'geo:within(longitude,latitude,"{'type':'Polygon','coordinates':[[[0,0],[0,2],[1,2],[1,0],[0,0]]]}")'.
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.executor.function.FunctionExecutor.initExecutor(FunctionExecutor.java:58)
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.ExpressionParser.parseExpression(ExpressionParser.java:427)
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.SelectorParser.getAttributeProcessors(SelectorParser.java:211)
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.SelectorParser.parse(SelectorParser.java:89)
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.QueryParser.parse(QueryParser.java:115)
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.SiddhiAppParser.parse(SiddhiAppParser.java:245)
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.SiddhiManager.createSiddhiAppRuntime(SiddhiManager.java:65)
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.SiddhiManager.createSiddhiAppRuntime(SiddhiManager.java:74)
        at uca.es.geoprueba.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:58)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7224)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7213)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2926)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/geotools/factory/StrictHints;
        at org.geotools.geometry.jts.JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory(Unknown Source:0)
        at org.wso2.extension.siddhi.gpl.execution.geo.internal.util.GeometryUtils.<clinit>(GeometryUtils.java:42)
        at org.wso2.extension.siddhi.gpl.execution.geo.internal.util.GeometryUtils.preparedGeometryFromJSON(GeometryUtils.java:75)
        at org.wso2.extension.siddhi.gpl.execution.geo.internal.util.GeoOperation.init(GeoOperation.java:57)
        at org.wso2.extension.siddhi.gpl.execution.geo.function.AbstractGeoOperationExecutor.init(AbstractGeoOperationExecutor.java:47)
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.executor.function.FunctionExecutor.initExecutor(FunctionExecutor.java:56)
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.ExpressionParser.parseExpression(ExpressionParser.java:427) 
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.SelectorParser.getAttributeProcessors(SelectorParser.java:211) 
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.SelectorParser.parse(SelectorParser.java:89) 
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.QueryParser.parse(QueryParser.java:115) 
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.SiddhiAppParser.parse(SiddhiAppParser.java:245) 
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.SiddhiManager.createSiddhiAppRuntime(SiddhiManager.java:65) 
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.SiddhiManager.createSiddhiAppRuntime(SiddhiManager.java:74) 
        at uca.es.geoprueba.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:58) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7224) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7213) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2926) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873) 
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.geotools.factory.StrictHints
        at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:738)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at org.geotools.geometry.jts.JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory(Unknown Source:0) 
        at org.wso2.extension.siddhi.gpl.execution.geo.internal.util.GeometryUtils.<clinit>(GeometryUtils.java:42) 
        at org.wso2.extension.siddhi.gpl.execution.geo.internal.util.GeometryUtils.preparedGeometryFromJSON(GeometryUtils.java:75) 
        at org.wso2.extension.siddhi.gpl.execution.geo.internal.util.GeoOperation.init(GeoOperation.java:57) 
        at org.wso2.extension.siddhi.gpl.execution.geo.function.AbstractGeoOperationExecutor.init(AbstractGeoOperationExecutor.java:47) 
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.executor.function.FunctionExecutor.initExecutor(FunctionExecutor.java:56) 
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.ExpressionParser.parseExpression(ExpressionParser.java:427) 
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.SelectorParser.getAttributeProcessors(SelectorParser.java:211) 
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.SelectorParser.parse(SelectorParser.java:89) 
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.QueryParser.parse(QueryParser.java:115) 
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.SiddhiAppParser.parse(SiddhiAppParser.java:245) 
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.SiddhiManager.createSiddhiAppRuntime(SiddhiManager.java:65) 
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.SiddhiManager.createSiddhiAppRuntime(SiddhiManager.java:74) 
        at uca.es.geoprueba.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:58) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7224) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7213) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2926) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/geotools/factory/Hints;
        at org.geotools.geometry.jts.JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory(Unknown Source:0) 
        at org.wso2.extension.siddhi.gpl.execution.geo.internal.util.GeometryUtils.<clinit>(GeometryUtils.java:42) 
        at org.wso2.extension.siddhi.gpl.execution.geo.internal.util.GeometryUtils.preparedGeometryFromJSON(GeometryUtils.java:75) 
        at org.wso2.extension.siddhi.gpl.execution.geo.internal.util.GeoOperation.init(GeoOperation.java:57) 
        at org.wso2.extension.siddhi.gpl.execution.geo.function.AbstractGeoOperationExecutor.init(AbstractGeoOperationExecutor.java:47) 
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.executor.function.FunctionExecutor.initExecutor(FunctionExecutor.java:56) 
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.ExpressionParser.parseExpression(ExpressionParser.java:427) 
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.SelectorParser.getAttributeProcessors(SelectorParser.java:211) 
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.SelectorParser.parse(SelectorParser.java:89) 
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.QueryParser.parse(QueryParser.java:115) 
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.SiddhiAppParser.parse(SiddhiAppParser.java:245) 
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.SiddhiManager.createSiddhiAppRuntime(SiddhiManager.java:65) 
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.SiddhiManager.createSiddhiAppRuntime(SiddhiManager.java:74) 
        at uca.es.geoprueba.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:58) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7224) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7213) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2926) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873) 
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.geotools.factory.Hints
        at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:738)
```

It seems that it can't find org.geotools class (StrictHints). 
I am trying to put the org.geotools in my classpath and adding in my dependencies but still not working.
How can I add the class from geotools to my project?
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have got proguard turned on? Also, according to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8256845/android-app-build-on-geotools-library-missing-native-java-libs I'm not sure if geotools is compatible with Android.

Comment: @mohru how can i look if proguard is turned on?

Comment: If you don't know, then probably it's not :) It's turned off in debug builds by default. It can be turned on in your `build.gradle` file `android{ buildTypes{ debug{ /*here*/ } release{ /*or here*/ } } }` by `minifiedEnabled true`. So unless you builded release version by mistake it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: In that case, I have ```minifiedEnabled false``` . For some reason, when compilate the maven depencency, it couldn't find the class. In project view, in section "External Libraries" -> "org.wso2.extension.siddhi.gpl.execution.geo: siddhi-gpl-execution-geo.jar" -> org -> geotools -> factory -> StrictHints.java So the class it seems to exist in the project. I don't know why it doesnt detect it.

Comment: It is found in gt-metadata so make sure you've included that module as a dependency

Comment: @IanTurton when I add gt-metadata as depencency i have the error  ```       Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method getGeometryFactory()Lcom/vividsolutions/jts/geom/GeometryFactory; in class Lorg/geotools/geometry/jts/JTSFactoryFinder; or its super classes (declaration of 'org.geotools.geometry.jts.JTSFactoryFinder' appears in base.apk!classes3.dex)
```                                       do you know what is happening?

Comment: You are trying to use GeoTools' SPI based factory finding code on Android which doesn't support it

Comment: @IanTurton I am using the next depencency: `implementation ('org.geotools:gt-metadata:17.1') ` from the repository: ` maven { url 'https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/release/'}` and I am having this error: `Failed resolution of: Lorg/geotools/geometry/jts/JTSFactoryFinder;`  Where can i find this class??

Comment: That is in gt-main - you really need to be using maven to handle the dependencies

Comment: I add the gt-main and I have the error i told you before (no static method...) I am using maven but what other shoud I use instead of maven??

Comment: Geotools does not support android

Comment: and why occur that??